# rigidbody.velocity assign attempt for 'gameobject' is not valid. Input velocity is {NaN, NaN, NaN}

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in Unity and I am currently getting this error when pulling up my menu.

Here is the script

```
private void OnAnimatorMove()
    {
        float delta = Time.deltaTime;
        enemyManager.enemyRigidBody.drag = 0;
        Vector3 deltaPosition = anim.deltaPosition;
        deltaPosition.y = 0;
        Vector3 velocity = deltaPosition / delta;
        enemyManager.enemyRigidBody.velocity = velocity;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `OnAnimatorMove` is also being called outside of `PlayMode` where `Time.deltaTime` most probably is simply `0`

=> division by `0` => generally not a good thing to do ;)

You could probably avoid that by checking

```
private void OnAnimatorMove()
{
    if(! Application.isPlaying) return;

    ...
}
```

or maybe

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(Time.deltaTime, 0f)) return;
```

Also see [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-properly-use-onanimatormove-without-breaking-timeline.600199/)

Comment: if(Mathf.Approximately(Time.deltaTime, 0f)) return; did the trick! Thank you so much for the answer